# ruby on rails using the paypal gem don' return the payer id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to user the paypal gem for ruby on rails to do the paying stuff with.

Most of the suff works fine, but I don't get the payer ID, for the last step the payment.execute() I need the payerID

my code looks like this:

```
##################################################################################
# Build Payment object
@payment = Payment.new({
   :intent => "sale",
   :payer => {
     :payment_method => "paypal"
   },
   :redirect_urls => {
       :return_url => url_for(:controller=>:movies,:action=>:play,:id=>@movie.id),
       :cancel_url => url_for(:controller=>:movies,:action=>:play,:id=>@movie.id)},
   :transactions => [{
     :item_list => {
         :items => [{
            :name => @movie.movietitle,
            :sku => "item",
            :price => @movie.movieprice,
            :currency => "USD",
            :quantity => 1 }]},
     :amount => {
         :total => @movie.movieprice,
         :currency => "USD" },
     :description => "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

   # Create Payment and return the status(true or false)
    if @payment.create
      @payment.id     # Payment Id
      redirect_to @payment.links[1].href
    else
     @payment.error  # Error Hash
    end
```

how can I get the payerID?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It says that the payment wasn't approved.

Comment: Did you got the solution How to get payer id from ?